# How to read with VueJs result from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js

Using NodeJS, I am retrieving data from MongoDB and trying to show the list of result. The retrieval works and the data arrives to my html. I can see in Chrome an array with N objects and the v-for directive creates N items in my HTML.
But, it can't access the fields inside each object in the array. It's all empty.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <ul class="collection">
        <li v-for="item in items" class="collection-item avatar" :key="item._id">
          <span class="title">{{ item.currencyPair }}</span>
          <p>{{ item.tradeOpenDate }} <br>
             {{ item.tradeDirection}}
          </p>
          <a href="/list/{{ item._id }}" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">send</i></a>
        </li>    
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        items: []
      },
      mounted: function() {
        var that = this;
        axios.get('/api/journal')
            .then(function(response) {
                if(response.status = 200) {
                    that.items = response.data;                     
                    console.log(that.items);
                } else {
                    console.log('error');
                }
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
      },
      methods: {

      }   
    })
</script>
```

In the server, this is how I retrieve and return the data:

```
.get(function(req, res) {
        Journal.find(function(err, jour) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(jour);
        });
    });
```

And, finally, looking at the inspector in Chrome, I can see that I get the data and it looks like this:

> Array[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WbZ4.png)0: Object1: Object__ob__: Observerlength: 2__proto__: Array

I am positive I am accessing the right field names, with the correct names.

What could be wrong?
Thanks

EDIT:
Adding the screenshot of the array of objects that is sent to my client. Could that be that its structure is not correctly read by VuejS?

[image]

EDIT2:

This is the screenshot of the Vue Dev Tools. Everything looks good?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks perfectly fine. A reduced example seems to work and I could not find a critical difference to your code: https://codepen.io/tuelsch/pen/XRXvZy

Allthough, you may want to consider to transfer your template markup into a separate tempalte. Your code would look like this:

```
<div id="app"></div>

<template id="list">
    <ul class="collection">
        <li v-for="item in items" class="collection-item avatar" :key="item._id">
          <span class="title">{{ item.pair }}</span>
          <p>{{ item.openDate }} <br>
             {{ item.direction}}
          </p>
          <a href="/list/{{ item._id }}" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">send</i></a>
        </li>    
    </ul>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      template: '#list',
      data: {
        items: []
      },
      mounted: function() {
        var that = this;
        axios.get('/api/journal')
            .then(function(response) {
                if(response.status = 200) {
                    that.items = response.data;                     
                    console.log(that.items);
                } else {
                    console.log('error');
                }
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
      },
      methods: {

      }   
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Wait a sec, this might not be true. I'll edit my answer shortly.

Comment: thanks for your help. I am indeed lost, I don't know why it is not working. It is meant to. I successfully receive from the server the array of objects and vuejs is able to loop around that array creating all the <li> elements in the view. But, it simply can't read the objects properties!

Comment: Have you tried inspecting your view with the vue.js devtools in chrome? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd Inspect your view and take a look at the values vue is recieving/setting.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of Dev Tools. What do you think?

Comment: The vue state looks good. Only thing I can think of: are the texts visually hidden (white font color or somewhere off screen -> inspect html). And what are the three errors in the console?

Comment: thanks for your support so far. Yeah, I thought it could've been a white font, unfortunately it is not :( The three errors are for the <img> tag. It's currently pointing to an image that doesn't exist. I am about to throw the towel :)